# Javascript multiple await in nodejs app - is there a better way to code this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

This code essentially gets some data from an api, and puts it in two arrays which I then render on a page using a rendering engine. It works, but I am wondering if there is a different approach to this that is better (because the first await call will have to complete before the second one does - maybe with Promise.all - but then how do I pass the arrays in to render? Most of the code examples I've seen directly return from Promise.all [return await Promise.all(etc)])

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const fic = [];
    const non = [];
    await getBooks(fic, API.URL_HARDCOVER_FICTION);
    await getBooks(non, API.URL_HARDCOVER_NONFICTION);
    res.render('layout', {results: {fic: fic, non: non}});
});

const getBooks = async (array, url)  => {
    await axios.get(url + "?api-key=" + API.Key)
        .then( async res => {
          const list = await res.data.results.books;
          list.forEach( book => {
            array.push(new Book(
              book.primary_isbn13,
              book.title,
              book.author));
          })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    return array;
}
```

Comment: If you change the signature of the `getBooks` method not to take an array as first param, but simply return one, you can then do: `const [fic, non] = await Promise.all([getBooks(API.URL...), getBooks(API.URL...)])` and keep your `render` call as-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

- Yes, you can use `Promise.all`. There is no issue with the order, as `Promise.all` will resolve to an array of fulfilment values that come in the same order as the array of promises you pass as argument.
- `getBooks` should not need an `array` parameter, as it has all it needs to create the array itself and then return it.
- Instead of `.forEach` and `push`, use `.map` and `return`.
- `res.data.results.books` is not a promise, so it is not needed to `await` that expression.

Adapted code:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const urls = [API.URL_HARDCOVER_FICTION, API.URL_HARDCOVER_NONFICTION];
    const [fic, non] = await Promise.all(urls.map(getBooks));
    res.render('layout', {results: {fic, non}});
});

const getBooks = async (url) => {
    const res = await axios.get(url + "?api-key=" + API.Key);
    return res.data.results.books.map(book => new Book(
        book.primary_isbn13,
        book.title,
        book.author
    ));
};
```

I left out the error handling. First make sure this works and then add a `try..catch` block.